# Count Items in file using VB

Tags: vbscript, count, scripting, delimiter

Kind of new to VBS. I'm trying to count the fields in the file and have this code.

```
Col()
Function Col()

Const FSpec = "C:\test.txt"
Const del = ","

  dim fs : Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  dim f : Set f = fs.OpenTextFile(FSpec, 1)
  Dim L, C

  Do Until f.AtEndOfStream
   L = f.ReadLine()
   C = UBound(Split(L, del))
   C = C +1

   WScript.Echo "Items:", C

  Loop
  f.Close

End Function
```

It works however, I don't want to count the delim inside " ".

Here's file content:

> 1,"2,999",3

So basically, I'm getting 4 items for now but I wanted to get 3. Kind of stuck here.

Comment: The elegant solution would be to use regular expressions. That may quickly get complicated though, given that you have embedded comma's. A pretty poor but quick solution would be to count the number of quotes and subtract 1 for every 2 quotes that you counted. That assumes that any value that is quoted in your data contains a comma! Not pretty, but quick.

Comment: A more tedious approach could be to parse every line character by character before splitting. If you encounter a quote, set a flag and continue to the next characters. If it is a comma, delete it, if it is a quote quote, reset the flag, and so on..

Comment: Richard L. Mueller has some decent examples on how to [Read CSV Files using VBScript](https://rlmueller.net/ReadCSV.htm)  Richard's first example is the second suggestion offered-up by Arno van Boven above.  Other alternatives include using ADO, OLEDB, and/or ODBC text driver to parse *.csv files.  Enjoy.

Comment: @ArnovanBoven thanks for the suggestions. was able to do it by using regex.

Answer (score 1):

For an example of my second suggestion, a very simple example could be something like this. Not saying it is perfect, but it illustrates the idea:

```
Dim WeAreInsideQuotes  'global flag
Function RemoveQuotedCommas(ByVal line)
    Dim i
    Dim result
    Dim current
    For i = 1 To Len(line)
        current = Mid(line, i, 1) 'examine character
        'check if we encountered a quote
        If current = Chr(34) Then
            WeAreInsideQuotes = Not WeAreInsideQuotes 'toggle flag
        End If
        'process the character
        If Not (current = Chr(44) And WeAreInsideQuotes) Then 'skip if comma and insode quotes
            result = result & current
        End If
    Next
    RemoveQuotedCommas = result
End Function
```